# Query having two table from different database each without db prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i have one table (tb1) in db1 and one tb2 in db2.

if i join two table as follow

`select *from db1.tb1 join db2.tb2 on tb1.id=tb2.id`

if db1 is default database then i can write it as following

`select *from tb1 join db2.tb2 on tb1.id=tb2.id`

now, what i want is to not use the prefix for tb2 i.e. (db2)

Comment: Why is supplying the prefix a problem? I think you are talking about schemas and not databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't  give prefix as `DB2`, then SQL Server will try to find the table in connected database only and your query will fail.

You can try creating `synonyms` for the table.

```
CREATE SYNONYM tbl2 FOR db2.dbo.tb2
```

This way you can hide the database.

Comment: is there anything apart from synonym that we can use ?

Comment: I am sure there is no other way to omit the db name for cross db access.

Comment: thank you very much. this is the best possible solution